# Any power of $(X_1, X_2,...,X_i)$ is primary in $k[X_1, X_2,...,X_n].$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $K$ be a field. Then how to show that all powers of the prime ideals $p_i=(x_1,\ldots,x_i)$ $(i=1,\ldots,n)$ are primary ideals in $K[x_1, \ldots,x_n]$ ?

It is easy when $i=n,$ but if $i<n$ how can I approach ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easy-to-prove criterion that goes as follows: an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is primary iff every zero-divisor of $R/I$ is nilpotent.

Let $R=k[X_1, X_2,\dots,X_n]$ and $p_i=(X_1, \dots, X_i)$ and $I=(p_i)^k$.

We have $R/I\cong (k[X_1,\dots,X_i]/(X_1,\dots,X_i)^k)[X_{i+1}, \dots X_n]$
So if we set $k[X_1,\dots,X_i]/(X_1,\dots,X_i)^k) =S$, $R/I$ is a polynomial ring in finitely many variables over $S$.

As you said, it is easy to see that $(X_1,\dots, X_i)^k$ is primary in $k[X_1,\dots, X_i]$, so all we have to do is to see that the property "every zero-divisor is nilpotent" is preserved when one takes a polynomial ring (inductively, we may reduce to the case of a polynomial ring in one variable.)

By one of the first exercises in Atiyah-Macdonald, all coeffcients of a zero-divisor polynomial are themselves zero-divisors and if all the coefficients of a polynomial are nilpotent, then the polynomial is nilpotent as well.

Comment: That $i$in the second last paragraph must be $n$ for me !

Comment: @user371231 you're right, I fixed it

Comment: MatheinBoulomenos Is it true that the ideal $(x_1,x_2)[x_3]$ is same as the ideal $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ where $(x_1,x_2)$ is the ideal in $K[x_1,x_2]$ ? I can't prove that. If this holds then everything is clear.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, then $(x_1,x_2)[x_3]$ should be $(x_1,x_2)$ in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$, not $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$

Comment: By $(x_1,x_2)[x_3]$ I mean the extension of the ideal $(x_1,x_2)$ from $K[x_1,x_2]$ to $K[x_1,x_2,x_3].$ My question is  for $i>1$ is it true that $(x_1,x_2)^i [x_3]$= $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^i$ in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ ?

Comment: The extension of a finitely generated ideal $(a_1, \dots a_n)$ is always generated by the images of the generators, thus the extension of $(x_1,x_2)$ from $K[x_1,x_2]$ to $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is just $(x_1,x_2)$ in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$

Comment: Now i get it ...sorry for the poor arguments